# Динамическое создание страниц

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp

Имеется адрес с ссылкой на статью о границах блоков в CSS **.../pages/border**

Динамическое формирование страниц происходит таким образом:

Сервер, увидев **pages**, определяет шаблон страницы, по **border** определяет какую запись брать с БД, и на основе этих данных отправляет пользователю построенную страницу. Корректно ли я понимаю решение данной задачи?
Как это реализовывается?

**EE** изучаю как два дня, поэтому за неграмотность извиняюсь. 
Прошу, если не дать ответ, а хотя бы натолкнуть куда рыть. Я даже в гугле грамотно столковать вопрос не смог, поэтому обращаюсь к вам. Спасибо заранее

Comment: И так тоже можно. В ЕЕ собрано много всякого

Comment: @Sergey , пожалуйста, укажите в каком направлении копать:) буду благодарен

Comment: Книжку купите. Хотя и не все они одинаково полезны, Но хоть что-то. Вот такая например "Изучаем Java EE 7". Сам не читал, только обложку видел:)

Comment: Тебе нужно загрузить код страницы(функцию загрузки реализовать, по URL, http://www.darkraha.com/rus/java/api/uri_url.php), выделить из нее нужные данные (парсер, это по поиску в тексте ищи), на  основе этих данных работать с БД(это JDBC) и строить новую страницу(это работа с текстом, потоками данных). По сути - 4 операции реализовать. Взаимодействие между ними либо строками, либо XML. А можно и свой класс придумать) В общем варианты разные, а основные направления я указал.

Comment: @Sergey спасибо за книгу

Comment: @FoeNicks спасибо большое за направление. вы прям сделали мне вечер. буду копать;)